# vb.net Contar controles con el prefijo del nombre

Tags: vb.net

con la siguiente linea de codigo puedo contar los controles textbox en un form actual;

```
Dim ControlsC As Integer = Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).AsQueryable.Count
```

pero no encuentro la opcion en Vb.Net para Filtrar solo los tengan un prefijo en el nombre....

algo como:

```
Dim ControlsC() As Object = Controls.Find("textbox*", True)
MessageBox.Show("Datos: " & ControlsC.Count)
```

me devuelve `Datos: 0`

O algo similar a:

```
Dim ControlsC As Integer = Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).AsQueryable.Where(Name Like "textbox").count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto puede servirte, cuenta los controles cuyo ID empieza por "ABC", aunque en vez de `StartsWith` puedes utilizar otros métodos

```
Dim ControlsC As Integer = Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).AsQueryable.Where(Function(s) s.ID.StartsWith("ABC")).Count
```

Comment: es correcto ya lo había encontrado no sabia que podía meterle una funcion anónima al where... y que podía pasar los parámetros del queryable...

Comment: en el próximo .net  framework deberían de morar o simplificar esto.. hay otros lenguajes que hacen esto mucho más fácil...